# Rails-Jquery Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Jquery is not defined in rails and I can not seem to find the problem.
It works when im writing javascript in the browser and index.html.erb but not in the javascripts/coffeescripts in the asset folder.

Here is the files

gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

coinflip.coffee

```
$ ->
 if $("meta[name='current-user']").length > 0 
  App.coinflip_update = App.cable.subscriptions.create 
  "CoinflipUpdateChannel",
   connected: ->

   disconnected: ->

   received: (data) ->
    console.log(data);
    if data.message == 'coin1'
      $('#coin').addClass 'heads'
      console.log 'it is head'
    else if data.message == 'coin2'
      $('#coin').addClass 'tails'
      console.log 'it is tails'
    else
      $('#coinflip-table').load location.href + ' #coinflip-table'
      $('#casinoNav').load location.href + ' #casinoNav'



  send_update: (message) ->
    @perform 'send_update', message: message
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
   <%= tag :meta, name: "current-user", data: {id: current_user.id} %>
  <% end %>
  <title>
   <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= current_user.email.split('@')[0] %> - Coins: <%= 
    current_user.coins %>
  <% else %>
    Casino
  <% end %>
</title>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= csp_meta_tag %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
<body>
 <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using javascript instead of coffeescript (because javasacript doesnt need to be compiled) and putting the jquery script tag before any other scripts in the head tag.